# Error while trying to look for specific information on a CSV using python (it may be pandas related)

Tags: python, pandas

I am using python to try to look at the information related to one specific name in a csv file. I am telling python to extract from the column named "Navn" the information related to "Molleavaerket A/S" but get an error (actually there may be 2 errors).

The code I am using:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    #get inflow data
    flowData=pd.read_csv('CSV_mal.csv',sep=";",encoding='latin-1')
    ##get concentration data
    ConData=pd.read_csv('CSV_Ana.csv',sep=";",encoding='latin-1') 

    #Added this line of code to see if python recognized the column names and     itdoes
    print(flowData.columns)

    idxLundtofte=flowData['Navn'].str.contains('Molleavaerket A/S')
```

The error I get is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/santiago/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-       packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)

    File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

    File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

    File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1618, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

    File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1626, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

    KeyError: 'Navn'


    During handling of the above exception, **another exception occurred**:

    Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "/Users/santiago/Desktop/Semester II/Modelling of environmental  processes  and technologies/Tutorials/#2- Python/2nd_ex", line 38, in <module>
    idxLundtofte=flowData['Navn'].str.contains('Molleavaerket A/S')

    File "/Users/santiago/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2800, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

    File "/Users/santiago/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2648, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

    File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 111, in  pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

    File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

    File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1618, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

    File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1626, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

     KeyError: 'Navn'
```

I read that the error could be related to Python not identifying the name of the column but when I use the "print(flowData.columns)" code, it prints out the name just as I have in the input. It returns the following:

```
                        'Index(['KommunenummerKode,**Navn**,NedlagtDato,MaalestedIdentifikator,MaalestedGeo,Maalested_Lat,Maalested_Lon,PunktkildeReference,MalestedNavn,M+S28lestedstypeKodeSc1076,Malestedstype,ProveDatoTid,SlutProveDatoTid,MaaltDatoTid,Aar,FeltudforerInstitutionKodeSc1025,Feltudforer CVR-nummer,FormalKode,Formal,ParameterKodeSc1008,Parameter,Resultat,EnhedKodeSc1009,Enhed,FravalgKontrol,FravalgStoftransport,DataKildeTekst,DataKvalitetRelationKey,BemaerkningTekst,OpdateretDatoTid,Navn'], dtype='object')'
```

Any idea why this error happened? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Use `sep=','` or omit `sep=";",` like  `flowData=pd.read_csv('CSV_mal.csv',encoding='latin-1')`, because `,` is default separator

Comment: It worked, thank you!